# Adding style tag in django inherited template

Tags: python, django, html, css, django-templates

I am new to Django. I want to add just a few lines of styling code in my Django template i.e 'blogs.html' which is already inheriting from a 'base.html' django template.But If I add a style tag and try to give a background image using {%static %} it doesnt work.

Blogs.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
        body{
               margin:0;
               padding:0;
        }

        box1{
               height:100vh;
               width:100%;
               background image:{%static 'images/ps1.jpg'%};
               background-size:cover;
        }
        box2{
               height:100vh;
               width:100%;
               background image:{%static 'images/ps2.jpg'%};
               background-size:cover;
        }
        box3{
               height:100vh;
               width:100%;
               background image:{%static 'images/ps3.jpg'%};
               background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="box1">
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming Your `{% block content %}` `{% endblock %}` 
is in html body but that CSS code should be in head. That's why it's not working.

If you really need this, then you can create a block on `base.html` `head` section.
Something like this

```
<head>
{% block mycss %} {% endblock mycss %}
</head>
```

and the in inherited html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% block mycss %} <style> Your entire css </style> {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    Body Part
{% endblock %
```